# Hide button conditionally using javascript and css

Tags: javascript

I need to display conditionally my shopping cart button using Javascript and Css. My goal is to hide the button when no items are present inside the cart.

The code of my button is:

```
<span id="mycartbutton" style="float: right; clear: both;">
<a class="button"href="$(shopping_cart_url)">Mon panier</a>
</span>
```

When nothing is present in the cart, the url look simply like this:

```
/.../mode=show_cart
```

When one or more items are present, the url look like this:

```
/.../mode=show_cart&cart_id=10332&first_reservation_id=717
```

Unfortunately I'm not a coder and I don't have any knowledges of javascript but I suppose is possible to make a check according to rendered url.

Actually I use the follow javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function on_site_form_loaded(event) {
    if (event=='product_list')
        document.getElementById('mycartbutton').style.display='none';
    }
</script>
```

..this allow me to hide the button on product list as desired BUT even if some items are inside the cart.

Somebody can tell me which conditional code I must use for check if the url contain for example the text "cart_id"? This will mean something is present inside the cart and will let me hide the button.

Comment: you shouldn't even render the button if there are no items in the cart. If you're not a code then I suggest hiring a coder that knows this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If your page is set up like this:

```
<ul id="cart">
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
<span id="mycartbutton"...>...</span>
```

Then you could use this CSS:

```
#cart:empty~#mycartbutton {display:none}
```

However this will only work if the cart button is a sibling of the cart itself (if there are element in between them, use `+` instead of `~`), and only if the cart's items are first-level children of the cart element.

If this is not possible, you will need to use JavaScript. Basically you can check the number of items at any time, something like `document.getElementById('cart').children.length`, and use that information to set `display:none` or `display:block` on your button.

Answer (score 0):

`url.indexOf()` should work for you. Try this:

```
<script>
    function check(url){
        if(url.indexOf("cart_id")>-1){
            // cart_id present do something
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the total URL is in a string Url, do a search for stiring "cart_id" and place it in a boolean.

```
cartIDFound = Url.search("cart_id");

if (cartIdFound){
    // ... cart id is found. items are in cart .. do domething
    // .. first,show button by setting visibility to visible and showing display
    document.getElementById('mycartbutton').style.visibility='visible';
    document.getElementById('mycartbutton').style.display='inline';
    // ... next, continue

}
else {
      //  .. cart id wasn't found; no items in cart.. do something different
      // first, hide the cart button
      document.getElementById('mycartbutton').style.visibility='hidden';
     document.getElementById('mycartbutton').style.display='none';
     // ... next, continue
}
```

Comment: Ok but in my case I need to do something (that mean apply css) if "cart_id" is not found and not the opposite. Could you please write down the full code by mixing your and my code?

Comment: Hi, I just modified the above same to hide the cart button when cart_id is not present, and to show the button if cart_id is present. Let me know if this works, thanks.

Comment: No this don't work. I don't know if is because I implemented not correctly your code in my code or if is for another reason. I need to keep the function on_site_form_loaded(event) if (event=='product_list'). Please note the URL who must be checked is the one rendered by the button and not URL page.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [**hide()**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function on_site_form_loaded(event) {
        if (event=='product_list')
            $("#mycartbutton").hide();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a best solution using CSS:

```
#mycartbutton a.button {
    display: none; 
}

#mycartbutton a.button[href*=cart_id] { 
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Iit is easier and more reliable because I got some conflict using JavaScript in my case.